# I am facing issue in the code with the function

Tags: r, select, xgboost

```
****library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(xgboost)
library(caret)
library(dplyr)

setwd("C:/Users/ASMD/Desktop/R files jnefjenfjne")

Data1 = as.data.frame(read_excel("r.xlsx"), header = TRUE)
head(Data1)
summary(Data1)
dim(Data1)
names <- names(Data1)

set.seed(100)

inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=Data1$TLS, p = 0.8, list = FALSE )

training <-Data1[inTrain,]




testing <-Data1[-inTrain,]
**X_train = xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(training %>% select(-TLS)))**


y_train = training$TLS
X_test = xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(testing %>% select(-TLS)))
y_test = testing$TLS****
```

The error which pops up is:

> X_train = xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(training %>% select(-TLS))) Error in
>   select(., -TLS) : unused argument (-TLS

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you please provide sample data? Please follow the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example Otherwise its hard for people to understand

Comment: Hey Bill ! I am new to R and this is my first piece of code. So, please bear with me.

Comment: here's, the sample data you are asking for ****TLS DevLLM DevLM DevCM DevSM1 DevSM2 DevH1 DevH2
3 632 938 1116 1116 -192 -1155 1155
4 317 38 -133 -133 -412 150 -150
2 186 162 -235 -235 -335 -154 154
3 261 278 64 64 -59 24 -24
3 213 102 23 23 -82 -132 132
1 59 140 146 146 20 -145 145
3 -313 -333 -77 -77 -370 250 -250
15 92 254 140 140 23 -130 130
7 16 18 3 3 -101 -54.5 54.5****
Basically TLS being dep variable and other predictor variables